# $f\begin{pmatrix}x \\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}e^x \cos y \\e^x \sin y\end{pmatrix}$ diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis

> $$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2,f\begin{pmatrix}x \\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}e^x \cos y \\e^x \sin y\end{pmatrix}$$

I want to find the 'largest' subset $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ so that $f |_D$ is a diffeomorphism.

And then I want to determine $f(D), df\big|_D(x)$ and $d(f\big|_D)^{-1}(y)$ $\forall x \in D, y \in f(D)$. I think the notation here is a bit confusing but let's say $x=(x_1,x_2)^T$.

As $\mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathbb{C}$ we can write $f$ as $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C},f(z)=e^{z}$.
My first question is: does $D$ have to be open? Depending on this I would choose $D_1=[0,2\pi)$ or $D_2=(0,2\pi)$ with $f(D_1)=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. How would $f(D_2)$ look like?

For $df\big|_D(x)$ I get:

$$df\big|_D(x)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{x_1}\cos x_2&&-e^{x_1}\sin x_2\\e^{x_1}\sin x_2 && e^{x_1}\cos x_2\end{pmatrix}$$

Is that correct?

And what's $df\big|_D^{-1}(y)$?